# Why is .htaccess behaving strangely? Passing the script-name itself instead of given GET variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this setup in my htdocs:

```
htdocs
htdocs/somedir
htdocs/somedir/process.php
htdocs/somedir/.htaccess
```

This is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ process.php?var=$1 [L]
```

What I believe is that this rule tells apache to start from the right-most letter and keep storing it unless it encounters a `/` So, in URL `http://127.0.0.1/somedir/foo`, `$1` should be `foo`. Right?

But when I go to this URL: `http://127.0.0.1/somedir/foo`, a print_r($_GET) in `process.php` outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [var] => process.php
)
```

Whereas I expect that it should say this:

```
Array
(
    [var] => foo
)
```

So why is `var`'s value is `process.php` and not `foo`? How to write this rewrite rule so that `var` gets the value `foo`?

**Sidenote:** No matter if I move this `process.php` & `.htaccess` to root OR any Second/Third/Fourth level, all the appropirate URLs produce same results:

Like:

```
http://127.0.0.1/foo             //process.php & .htaccess in root
http://127.0.0.1/somedir/foo     //process.php & .htaccess in htdocs/somedir
http://127.0.0.1/somedir/2nd/foo //process.php & .htaccess in htdocs/somedir/2nd
```

**Update 01:**

I have noticed that `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]` is equal to `var=foo`, whereas `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is `var=process.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first look I'd say your regex in the rewrite rule is buggy. 
Try changing it from

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ process.php?var=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ process.php?var=$1 [L]
```

If you anchor it towards the start of the string ("^") there is no way it can match, given you have a "/" in the string.

---

Using RewriteRules on a per-directory level is a little more complex. The REQUEST_URI might not be what you expect, so some rules produce unexpected results. However, you can often solve problems when refering to matches in RewriteConditions. In this case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "([^/]+) HTTP"   
RewriteRule ^ process.php?var=%1 [L]
```

(note the '%' instead of a '$' in the rule)

Comment: No effect. Still `var` is populated with `process.php` instead of `foo`

Comment: Well if I test it things work like this. Have a try yourself: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Yeah, it works there and even at [http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) It shows that `process.php?var=foo` is resulting URL. But on my local XAMPP, it is not Could you please try it on your local server? Also I have noticed that `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]` is equal to `var=foo`, whereas `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is `var=process.php`

Comment: Indeed, rewrite rules work slightly different when used on a directory bases (".htaccess"). Certain things don't make sense there. I suggest you raise the log level for rewriting ("RewriteLog" & "RewriteLogLevel") and consult the log file. That information usually helps.

Comment: I appended a modified rule set that works on one of my servers.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. In the meanwhile, I used `RewriteRule (^...)$ process.php?var=$1 [L]` and `http://127.0.0.1/somedir/2/r4/foo` is working as expected. `var` is poupulated with `foo` But now, the problem is because I am using `...` in regex, it is catching exact three letters. What is the regex equivalent of telling to to catch all letters until you find a `/` ?

Comment: ?!? I doubt you are using the regex you have specified here and get results as written. This approach won't led to a result, since the string you test against simply does not contain 'foo' when using a RewriteRule on a per-directory basis. What do you dislike with the solution I gave ?

Comment: No dislike, actually I appreciate it. It was just that while waiting for your answer, I stumbled upon that `three-dot` variation.